# SurveyMonkey: unique ID in Survey End Page URL

Tags: surveymonkey

On the **Survey End Page** of SurveyMonkey I need an URL with the **unique ID** of the Survey. Example: http://www.example.com?id={unique ID}

When a user is finished with his survey, I need to redirect the user to my site. My Site need to know the unique ID of the survey.

In SurveyMonkey it is possible to create a [custom end page](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/What-are-the-Survey-Completion-options) with a custom url, but I dind't figured out, how to add the unique ID to this custom URL.